# In older versions of Rails, what are the methods to say, controller <--> view sharing methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, controllers

I think in newer versions of Rails, there are ways to say, "share these methods between controllers and views" using something like

```
controller.helper
controller.helper_method
```

(I am not sure if they are).  But what if these methods are missing in older versions of Rails?  How can you tell Rails to share methods between controllers and views?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then something is probably wrong with your app. `helper_method` has been available since Rails 1.0.

http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: the code in the original post is actually in the controller: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/facebooker2-0.0.5/lib/facebooker2/rails/controller.rb line 41`